# Cloud9 Watir/Selenium Testing

Tags: selenium, cloud9-ide

I have set up Cloud9 and Codeship for a simple Continuous Integration and Delivery system. It works well for developing my website/app. Has anyone been able to develop and run browser based Cucumber tests from within the Cloud9 IDE? If so, what kind of set-up did it require?

PS. I have been trying to get the Watir/Selenium chromedriver installed and working with the 'headless' gem.

Comment: In addition, this is my first question, so I would prefer comments explaining why it is a bad question (-2).

Comment: SO expects to see your research and effort towards the success. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

First an explanation. I found it very easy to set up github, c9.io, and codeship for CI and CD using Cucumber for acceptance testing on Codeship. Unfortunately, developing the Cucumber tests was difficult, because I had to commit, push, and examin the failing Integration tests on codeship. I wanted to be able to quickly run and debug Cucumber scenarios in the IDE. But, there is no browser for watir/selenium to open. Thus the question.

After a day of searching and hint from c9.io on twitter, I have consensed the solution down to two steps ...

1. Install firefox and xvfb: **sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb**
2. Run cucumber in an xvfb context: **xvfb-run cucumber**